# Can I copy string from two dimensional array to one dimensional array (Array&Pointers)

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I found quiet tricky in copying string from two dimensional array to one dimensional array. So I made access those value by address. It is working fine inside for loop. Is the one-dimensional array is really copied with two-dimensional array value.

```
char *str[4] = {"i " "California", "ii " "Texas", "iii " "Florida", "iv " "Washington"};        //two dimensional array
int r = 0, c, i = 0;
char *temp;      //one dimesional array

for(r = 0; r < 4; r++){
    c = 0;
    while(*(str[r]+c) != '\0'){
        printf("%c", *(str[r]+c));
        c++;
        temp = &str[r][c];
        printf("%c", *temp);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

return 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use calloc for allocation temp pointer memory size.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char *str[4] = {"i " "California", "ii " "Texas", "iii " "Florida", "iv " "Washington"};        //two dimensional array
    int r = 0;

    for(r = 0; r < 4; r++)
    {
        char *temp = (char*) calloc (strlen(str[r]) ,sizeof(char));
        strcpy(temp, str[r]);
        printf("%s", str[r]);
        printf("\n");
        free(temp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: in C, the returned type from any of the heap allocation functions: `calloc` `realloc` `malloc` 1) has type `void*` which can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting just clutters the code making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.   suggest removing the cast.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 0):

assuming:

```
char array2dim[x][y];
```

then to create a 1 dimensional array..

```
char array1dim[x*y];

memcpy( array1dim, array2dim, x*y );
```